# Why to add mean in the reconstruction in PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, projection, pca

Suppose that X is our dataset (still not centered) and X_cent is our centered dataset (X_cent = X - mean(X)).

If we are doing PCA projection in this way Z_cent = F*X_cent, where F is matrix of principal components, that is pretty obvious that we need to add mean(X) after reconstruction Z_cent.

But what if we are doing PCA projection in this way Z = F*X? In this case we don't need to add mean(X) after reconstruction, but it gives us another result.

I think that something wrong with this procedure (construction-reconstruction), when it applied to the non-centered data (X in our case). Can anyone explain how it works? Why can't we do construction/reconstruction phase without this subracting/adding mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives us another result"?

Comment: @bogatron, I mean that [transpose(F) * F * X] is not equal to [transpose(F) * F * X_cent + mean(X)], so the result after reconstruction is different.

Comment: How are you computing `F`?

Comment: @bogatron F is just matrix of first K principal components (K eigenvectors of cov(X))

Comment: If you don't keep all PCs, then you lose information and can't reconstruct the original data vector.

Comment: @bogatron, yes, of course, I understand it. But still PCA can reconstruct the original data vectors (of course, with some error). I mean that after these two procedures of reconstruction: [transpose(F) * F * X] and [transpose(F) * F * X_cent + mean(X)] - we get different results (of course, both of them contain an error if we don't keep all PCs).

Comment: But the second (centered) version *does not* contain reconstruction error of the mean vector (since you never transformed that part) so the errors between the two versions will be different.

Comment: @bogatron, I agree, good point. But why it's better to reconstruct the X_cent instead of X? Can't get it. Probably, it would be more clear from the mathematical point of view.

Comment: @bogatron, actually, we can choose some `C` which has the same dimension as `X` and consider the following construction/reconstruction:

[transpose(F) * F * (X - C) + C] - with custom `C`. We can choose `C` to be equal mean(X), but can choose something else. Is there any results that choosing `C` to be equal mean(X) is the best choice or smth like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retain all Principal Components, then reconstruction of the centered and non-centered vectors as described in your question would be identical. The problem (as indicated in your comments) is that you are only retaining `K` principal components. When you drop PCs, you lose information so the reconstruction will contain errors. Since you don't have to reconstruct the mean in one of the reconstructions, you don't introduce errors w.r.t. the mean there so the reconstruction errors of the two versions will be different.

Reconstruction with fewer than all PCs isn't quite as simple as multiplying by the transpose of the eigenvectors (`F'`) because you need to pad your transformed data with zeros but to keep things simple, I'll ignore that here. Your two reconstructions look like this:

```
R1 = F'*F*X
R2 = F'*F*X_cent + X_mean
   = F'*F*(X - X_mean) + X_mean
   = F'*F*X - F'*F*X_mean + X_mean
```

Since the reconstruction is lossy, in general, `F'*F*Y != Y` for matrix Y.  If you retrained all PCs, you would have `R1 - R2 = 0`. But since you are only retaining a subset of the PCs, your two reconstructions will differ by

```
R2 - R1 = X_mean - F'*F*X_mean
```

Your follow-up question in the comments regarding why it's better to reconstruct `X_cent` instead of `X` is a bit more nuanced and really depends on why you are doing PCA in the first place. The most fundamental reason is that the PCs are with respect to the mean in the first place so by not centering the data prior to transforming/rotating, you aren't really decorrelating the features. Another reason is that the numeric values of the transformed data are often orders of magnitude smaller when centering the data first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
But still, can we introduce variable `C` and somehow prove that for the following reconstruction `F'*F*(X-C)+C` it's better to take C equal to mean(X)?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "better". If you use something other than the mean, then the transformed features can't be guaranteed to be uncorrelated. That said, I suspect one could probably prove that setting `C = X_mean` would minimize the average reconstruction error (if that is your goal) but that's beyond the scope of your original question so you should probably post a new one (perhaps [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com)).